# WPF application database connect with remote database

Tags: wpf

I am creating a WPF application and there are two databases, one is on client computer and the other one is on a remote server. And my client asks me to sync these two databases. He asked me when my WPF application connects to the internet, it should sync local data to the remote server, and if not connected to the internet, then it should save data locally.

Tell me is there a way to connect local and remote server, can WPF access two different databases on two different computers via internet

Comment: WPF is a **GUI** technology - it has no provisions to connect to databases.....

Answer (score 0):

This basically boils down to using two different connection strings where you need them (either via ADO or EF or however you're accessing your data).

```
void doStuff() {

    using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection("your first connection string here"))
        using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand) {

        cmd.Connection = conn;
        // do stuff with command        

    }

    using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection("your second connection string here"))
        using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand) {

        cmd.Connection = conn;
        // do stuff with command        

    }   

}
```

To access the remote database, you need the correct credentials, connection string, and the remote db must allow incoming connections.  Your client should have details.

For a more configuration-based approach, you might do something like this:

```
<connectionStrings>
    <add name="LocalConnection" connectionString="your first connection string here" />
    <add name="RemoteConnection" connectionString="your second connection string here" />
</connectionStrings>
```

and use it like so:

```
string connstr = System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["LocalConnection"].ConnectionString;
```

Or wire those up to your entity framework/ORM classess accordingly.